# http error on small PDF file upload to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I've been trying to resolve an issue we're having with a wordpress site and the host (godaddy) is being less than helpful as they can't recreate the problem on their side. One of the other admins on the site asked if I could look into why he couldn't upload a pdf file (only 212k)

I've tried all the obvious things, different files including .png adding the up memory limit code to the config file deactivating the theme and plugin files and nothing is working. I can still upload .jpg files though

The baffling thing is godaddy support tried uploading a file and said it worked fine. I've tried uploading the same pdf file to another site i'm admin on and it worked first time, also the other admin is based in another town from me so I know it's nothing to do with my connection or the file? really stumped on this one

Comment: give me specific error message you are getting from wp and possibly screenshot.

Comment: I came in the next morning and it was working perfectly, It was just "http error" thats all the info it gave me. Still a mystery to me but I hjave a suspicion someone godaddy had a looka t something in the backend after they finished talking with me